# Designing a Web Scraper for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, web-scraping

I am designing a web scraper for WP7, using HttpWebRequest and HtmlAgilityPack. The problem is that when i invoke it, it runs asynchronously and thus, I cannot use it on the main thread. I have a separate class called 'WebScraper' for the fetching part that has the 'executeCommand' method, which takes the url and the xpath as arguments and calls request.beginGetResponse. I call the 'executeCommand' from main().

Answer (score 0):

You can find how three different way to get the response back when making an asynchronous request in windows phone in the reply to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910192/how-to-get-response-value-from-callback-function-wp7/18916261#18916261).